# Blank placeholder for bootstrap glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with sorting bootstrap glyphicons in the header.  The icon is only shown if the table is being sorted by that particular header.  When I click the cell, it changes the sizing of the table.  The table is dynamic, so I'd prefer not fixing the cell sizes.  Is there a way I can put a placeholder in there that takes the place of the glyphicon?

I know how the javascript will work to hide it, I just don't know how to do the css to give the span some size.

(this is bootstrap 3.0 btw)...

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"><span>
```

is the particular icon.  Chrome says that it's 16px wide when displayed.

The actual project is a little more complicated, here's a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/N6nkW3e4gDdpQdtRC8ue?p=preview

Comment: you need to wrap it in a div that has a span on it, or for version 3 col-lg-# - if you post more code I can be more specific

Comment: added a plunkr so you can see what's going on

Comment: cant you change the color of the icon to match the background?

Comment: @Tarik That did it...it feels a little contrived but it works.  Had to rig up an ng-style since it doesn't look like you can have multiple ng-class directives or multiple expressions in a single ng-class directive.

Comment: looks like you figured it out

Comment: @matt Lambert yeah, tarik was right. Just don't have an answer

Comment: implemented this same feature and having the same problem! was trying to avoid just hard coding a spacer when a column is not sorted

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I don't think there's a whitespace character in the [glyphicon font](http://glyphicons.com/).

Why don't you just use a transparent font color?

```
.glyphicon-none:before {
    content: "\2122";
    color: transparent !important;
}
```

The \2122 is a minus sign. Use it like a normal icon:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></i>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for as well!  Only I used `content: "\e094";` (the down arrow) so that my spacing didn't change at all.

Comment: interestingly, unicode has appropriate space characters at /620 and /1879 so you can use those codes without the transparency rule

Comment: The spacing was not correct for me, until I used @Balrog30's suggestion of the `\e094` character.

Comment: `visibility: hidden` worked better for me that transparent color

Answer (score 10):

Just hide the icon's element with `visibility: hidden;`. E.g.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" style="visibility: hidden"><span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but was also using angularJs. I've done the following to resolve the issue.

add new class to css

```
.glyphicon-hide {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Then in template I can use

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" ng-class="{'glyphicon-hide': conditionValue}></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was setting the style of the table to `style="table-layout: fixed"`. After this, the column widths of my table stayed the same, whether an icon was shown next to the column header or not.

Here's the code of the table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th ng-click="order('col1')">
      Column Header 1
      <span class="glyphicon" ng-show="orderType == 'col1'"
        ng-class="orderReverse ? 'glyphicon-chevron-down' : 'glyphicon-chevron-up'"></span>
    </th>
    <th ng-click="order('col2')">
      Column Header 2
      <span class="glyphicon" ng-show="orderType == 'col2'"
        ng-class="orderReverse ? 'glyphicon-chevron-down' : 'glyphicon-chevron-up'"></span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

The `order()` function sets the `orderType` and flips `orderReverse`. With the help of `ng-show`, an arrow is shown on the header only if the table is sorted by that column. No need for an invisible glyphicon or anything like that.